# Induction is the only way?

Tags: proof-theory

Are there any statements that are true and can only be proved by induction?

(In most of the proofs I saw the induction proof shed some light on another way of proving a statement e.g. with divisibility problems, after solving it by induction you can guess how you should factor the original expression to get the result directly)

Comment: Is your question a meta-mathematics one? I mean, if we are not using higher axioms, then we can by no means no if there can be "only one" way of proof; for it may be just the case that another potential proof is not known to us.

Comment: Undecidability is meta-mathematical; a property of a statement that cannot be proved nor be disproved within a given formal system, roughly speaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In set theory the set $\omega$ of natural numbers is constructed on base of the axiom of infinity. This as the smallest set that contains $\varnothing$ as element and is closed under the operation $a\mapsto a\cup\{a\}$.

After that several properties of natural numbers are proved by induction. For instance the fact that all natural numbers are transitive sets. This by showing that the set $b:=\{n\in\omega\mid n\text{ is transitive}\}$ also contains $\varnothing$ as element and is closed under the operation $a\mapsto a\cup\{a\}$ (induction).

Then $\omega\subseteq b\subseteq\omega$ or equivalently $b=\omega$, wich means that every $n\in\omega$ is transitive.

I don't think there is a way to avoid induction here.

Answer (score 6):

Saying something *cannot* be proven by any other means but induction is quite a bold statement, and I am not capable of giving it. It is also not an entirely well defined statement, unless you formally define all your axioms (one of which is induction) and then say

> "which statements cannot be proven if I remove induction from my set of axioms?"

But I think that's not your question and that your question is more about the proofs you meet during the first years of studying math.

In that case, I would say that technically speaking, many proofs cannot be performed without at least implicitly using induction. For example, if I tell you I have a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ defined as

- $a_0=3$,
- $a_n = a_{n-1} + 3$ for all $n\geq 1$

then I see no way of getting around induction if you want to prove that $a_n$ is divisible by $3$ for all $n$. For example, you may say

> Oh that's easy, you can see that $a_n = 3n + 3$ for all $n$, so since $a_n = 3k$ for some $k$, it is divisible by $3$!

But then, how would you prove that $a_n = 3n + 3$ is true without using induction?